# Is there any graph example other than the complete graph where Diameter(G) = Radius(G)?

Tags: math, graph

We know that, for any graph G, Radius(G) ≤ Diameter(G) ⩽ 2*Radius(G). I was wondering whether there is any graph other than the complete graph, where Radius(G) = Diameter(G).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Interesting question, but suitable for math.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The complement of the complete graph! If all vertices have no edge, both `D` and `R` are equal. To be more accurate, there is a class of graphs that are called [vertex-transitive graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex-transitive_graph). Obviously, their radius and diamter are equal (see this [ref](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/365397/356329)).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the graph should be connected.